# como realizo inner join en la misma tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
    VENTAS: almacen_id, numero_orden, fecha_orden,  cantidad,  forma_pago,  titulo_id
```

Tengo que listar  los id de almacén, números de orden y la cantidad para las ventas que realizo el título “Prolonged Data Deprivation: Four Case Studies” el día 29 de mayo de 2013

Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
select almacen_id,numero_orden,cantidad,titulo_id,fecha_orden
    from ventas 
    where titulo_id = “Prolonged Data Deprivation: Four Case Studies"   no se como juntarlo con la fecha

 Muchas gracias de antemano
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo agrega una condicion mas. (El formato de fecha podria variar dependiendo como lo tengas en la BD)

```
select almacen_id,numero_orden,cantidad,titulo_id,fecha_orden
    from ventas 
    where titulo_id = 'Prolonged Data Deprivation: Four Case Studies'
    and fecha_orden = '2013-05-29'
```